# ActiveRecord cannot delete a record

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have my AttachmentsMembers table with the migration as:

```
class AttachmentsMembers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :attachments_members, :id => false do |t|
      t.references :attachment, :null => false
      t.references :member, :null => false
    end

    add_index :attachments_members, [:attachment_id, :member_id]
  end
end
```

If I try to delete any record from my console then I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: ...OM "attachments_members" WHERE "attachments_members"."" = $1
                                                                ^
: DELETE FROM "attachments_members" WHERE "attachments_members"."" = $1
from /home/icicle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@ltbuddy/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `prepare
```

Code for AttachmentsMember model:

```
class AttachmentsMember < ActiveRecord::Base
  #Relationships
  belongs_to :attachment
  belongs_to :member
end
```

In attachment model:

```
  belongs_to :user, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :referable, polymorphic: true

  has_many :attachments, as: :referable, :dependent => :destroy

  has_many :attachments_members, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :members, :through => :attachments_members, :dependent => :destroy
```

In member model:

```
  belongs_to :user, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'
  belongs_to :case, class_name: 'Case', foreign_key: 'case_id'
  belongs_to :user_type, class_name: 'UserType', foreign_key: 'user_type_id'

  has_many :attachments_members, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :attachments, :through => :attachments_members, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :documents_members, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :documents, :through => :documents_members, dependent: :destroy
```

Even if do AttachmentsMember.last from my console I get the same error but AttachmentsMember.first works.

Any someone explain why the issue is coming?

Comment: Can you please show the model, and also the command you are using in the console?

Comment: @WayneConrad have editted the post

Comment: Can someone please tell me the reason for the above issue?

Comment: Resolved the issue by creating the primary key for AttachmentsMember table

Comment: You can answer your own question, and then give it the answer the checkmark.  This may help someone in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the issue by creating the primary key for AttachmentsMember table